# UITableViewCell superscripts & subscripts

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to display subscript or superscript text in a UITableViewCell without making custom cells?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do in better detail? Maybe post a picture? Your biggest issue is that standard text display on iPhone doesn't support super/subscript, but you can probably get away without subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I have a table that is meant to list mathematical concepts.  Some of these include numbers with exponents, or variable names with subscripts (like H0, where the '0' is a subscript 0).  I'm getting by for now by using images, but I'd like a better way of doing this without going to the trouble of making a custom cell that uses a UIWebView in place of the usual text label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need numbers, use Unicode characters 2070..2079 for superscript and 2080..2089 for subscript.

If you need more, I suggest to use a UIWebView. With HTML tags <sup> and <sub> you can format your text and even add style with bold, italic, underline...

Good luck Cruinh!